# using include_once causes undefined variable notice

Tags: php

I have a file named "config.php" which contains a variable named `$unit_names`. In a class I have the following method which returns unit name by it's id. I use this method for all rows in a table, but the problem is `config.php` is included only in the first call to the method. next calls cause the notice: `undefined variable $unit_names...`

If I replace `include_once` by `include` the notice disappears. But why? `include_once` should load the `config.php` file.

```
public function get_unit_name($unit_id) 
    {   
            include_once("config.php");
            return $unit_names[$unit_id];
    }
```

Comment: `but the problem is config.php is included only in the first call to the method` But that sounds like [include_one is doing exactly what it's supposed to do](http://php.net/include_once), doesn't it?

Comment: I have an idea but you need to post more (other occurences of `include_once`, anything in between, contents of `config.php`).

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to put the `include_once` outside the function?

Comment: You have a singular in the notice (undefined variable $unit_name), and a plural ($unit_names) in the code. Is that a typo?

Comment: @JanDvorak `config.php` has just the variable `unit_names`. there is no function or class

Comment: @lortabac Yes it was a type. fixed

Comment: @Pekka You are right. I edited post

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`include_once` will not load the specified file *at least* once, it will load it *exactly* once! If you call the function the second time, the file has already been included and will therefore not be included again, hence the error message.

The idea with this is that you use `include_once` / `require_once` when you include files that contain function or class definitions, i.e., files that would produce an error if they were loaded more than once. If it's okay to load a file twice or more times, always use `include()` instead of `include_once()`.

Consider something like this instead (to save the cost of re-including the file every time):

```
private $unit_names = null;

public function get_unit_name($unit_id) {   
    if ($this->unit_names === null) {
        include("config.php");
        $this->unit_names = $unit_names;
    }

    return $this->unit_names[$unit_id];
}
```

Comment: Ok. but if the file has already been included why do I get this notice? if it has been included, the variable should be available

Comment: The first time you make a call to "get_unit_name()", the `include_once()` statement gets replaced by the content of the specified file (that obviously contains the declaration of `$unit_name`, so everything is fine). The second time, however, PHP evaluates the `include_once()` statement again and notices that the file has already been included and shall therefore not be included again (because the `_once` edition was used) - for this second call, the include statement will therefore be just ignored, or "removed".

Comment: `...and notices that the file has already been included` So if it has already been included, the variable should be available in the next calls!!

Comment: No, those variables are local to the function scope and vanish after the first call is complete, when the interpreter leaves the function and continues with the code outside. At the second call, these variables are not present any more and (due to the "_once") do not get re-created. An include is only "permanent", if the included code contains something global, e.g., a class, function or constant definition.

Comment: Thanks. where is this documented in?: "An include is only "permanent", if the included code contains something global, e.g., a class, function or constant definition"

Comment: I don't think this is specifically documented somewhere as it isn't a "special feature". It's valid PHP code to write `$a = 1; $a = 1;` but not `class A {} class A {}`. Also, variables are always local to the function scope by default while class-definitions etc. are always global.